# How can I access a record in a library in Clojure?

Tags: interface, clojure, namespaces, record

I'm writing a library that implements a protocol and trying to access the record outside the namespace.

`storage.clj` contains the record:

```
(defrecord FrienduiStorage []
  f-glob/FrienduiStorage
  (get-all-users [this]
   (db/get-all-users)))
```

I require it like so `[sventechie.friendui-mysql.storage :refer :all]`.
Then instantiate it like this `(def FrienduiStorageImpl (->FrienduiStorage))` but this doesn't work: `(get-all-users (FrienduiStorageImpl))` "RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: get-all-users in this context". What am I doing wrong?

The full library repo is at (http://github.com/sventechie/friendui-mysql/).
I've made a minimal usage example (http://github.com/sventechie/friendui-mysql-example/).

Comment: on which of the `get-all-users` do you get the exception? did you also require your `db`?

Comment: the record must be imported as a regular class. more info here https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord#example-542692d2c026201cdc326f87

Comment: The `get-all-users` function var is defined in the `de.sveri.friendui.globals` namespace - are you requiring that namespace where you call `get-all-users`? The implementation provided in `storage.clj` doesn't create a var in that namespace - you have to refer to the original var definition to call the fn.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I'd recommend against re-using the protocol name as the name of the record type that implements it.

Comment: Alex, good idea. I was trying to slavishly follow @sveri in his `friendui-datomic` implementation, but doubted it was best practice.

Comment: @TobyCrawley Thanks, I'm now requiring `db` as well, since it has an implementation of `get-all-users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formalize @mavbozo's comments to your question into an answer, you need to add an import to the regular class

So definition is

```
(ns sventechie.friendui-mysql.storage)
(defrecord FrienduiStorage [])
```

and usage is:

```
(ns somewhere.else
  (:require [sventechie.friendui-mysql.storage :refer :all])
  (:import [sventechie.friendui-mysql.storage.FrienduiStorage]))
```

Comment: Where is the record class being used by name?

Comment: With this I'm getting `FileNotFoundException: Could not locate sventechie/friendui_mysql/storage/FrienduiStorage__init.class or sventechie/friendui_mysql/storage/FrienduiStorage.clj` -- see my minimal usage example added to the question.

Comment: (:import [sventechie.friendui-mysql.storage.FrienduiStorage]) works.